# Data type mismatch in criteria expression vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using VB.Net connecting to MS Access database. I think SQL syntax is wrong because before i add WHERE clause, it works. When i add WHERE clause, i got error ' data type mismatch in criteria expression'. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here is my code

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where [OperationID] ='" & TextBoxOpID4.Text & "'", myConnection)
        Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(ds)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds
```

Additional info: `textboxOpID4 is enabled false`

Comment: what is data type of `operationid`?

Comment: data type is number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make something like this

```
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Sum([Shark Individual Weight]) From FishCaught Where [OperationID] =" & TextBoxOpID4.Text , myConnection)
Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable()
da.Fill(ds)
DataGridView2.DataSource = ds
```

I quite use this kind of query when the `where clause` is a number because if you do put **`'`** in a number column the output would be string which produces the error for example the `ColumnID = 5` your code is like this `ColumnID = '5'` which is wrong especially if it is an `AutoNumber` field so do not insert a datatype number inside `'` so it will not become a string

Comment: Good to know, Happy Coding and also please see the edited answer so you can learn more.

Comment: This code is _wide open_ to sql injection security hacks.  You should use parameterized queries to mitigate this.

Comment: ...as well, SQL parameters allow you to specify the datatype rather than having the DB Provider guess...which was the OP's problem.